# Функция render не видит папку template

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, render, python-3.7

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот текст исключения и код с функцией render.

index.html Сам по себе работает, но вот в djsngo приложении не открывается.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как устранить проблему.
Заранее благодарен

Comment: Каталог должен называться template**s**

Comment: добавил s ничего не изменилось кроме имени файла. (Обо фото новые)

Comment: В заголовке ошибки подсказка, что он ищет шаблон по адресу /blog/ и ничего не находит

Comment: а если просто `index.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Убедитесь, что добавили Blogsapp_1 в INSTALLED_APPS;
2) Проверьте пути, по которым Django ищет Ваши шаблоны.

*settings.py:*

```py
import os


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'Blogsapp_1'
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ...
]
```

*views.py:*

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def posts_list(request):
    return render(request, 'Blogsapp_1/index.html')
```